# New rear wheel to 8-speed Shimano Citybike, don't know what to look for

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel, replacement

My current rear wheel wont rotate around the hub anymore, so I need a replacement. I don't know what to look for, but I have this info:

Bike is an Avenue Airbase, dont know how old, but more than 3 years.

135mm hub spacing between rear forks.

28inch wheel with 25mm tire.

8 Shimano gears.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/Waka2WUs3RybQXbL7

Also: What do I need to take apart the wheel and check the bearings(Drum brake)?

Thanks :)
[image]

Comment: Can you also post close-up pictures of the hub, viewed from an angle similar to the one you've posted, but larger?  Where the hub body is visible? That will help a lot in identifying the hub. Also, a close up of the gears end-on to the axle to identify the exact cassette?  That will also provide a lot of information about the hub as well.  Providing the exact make and model of your bike would help, too.

Comment: @Andrew Henle 
Updated with pics.

Answer (score 1):

In general here we don't give [specific product recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), so instead let's look at what your options are:

## Replace The Wheel

Based on your question you know the spacing of the hub, and you know the size of cassette. You should be able to easily find a replacement online or at your local bike shop. You may have to chat with someone for a bit to make sure you get the right thing. The main things you need to be concerned about are either transferring or replacing your

- 8 speed cassette - if you do that yourself it's easy but does require a special lock nut tool and chain whip.
- Brake Rotor - I don't have a bike with disc brakes, so I can't say for sure, but you would likely only need a set of hex wrenches to do that.

Or most bike shops will swap the parts for you for free when you buy the wheel.

## Rebuild The Wheel With a New Hub

If the hub is truly shot, but the rim and spokes are in good condition, you can talk to  your shop about having the wheel rebuilt with a new hub. You may have to replace spokes as well if the flange of the hub sits higher or lower. Depending on the labor cost and how nice a while you would have picked above, the cost of rebuilding a wheel can approach or exceed the cost of buying a new wheel outright. But you would have the satisfaction of not contributing to our throw-away society.

## Repair The Hub

It's possible that there is a simple bearing issue or some other easily repairable problem with the hub. Steps to rebuild a hub would be a different question, and if you search here you will find several posts of advice. But if you are going to the shop anyway to explore **Replacing** or **Rebuilding**, you might as well take the wheel with you and see if you can get out on the cheep with a simple repair.

As far as tools if you want to attempt the [overhaul](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hub-overhaul-and-adjustment) yourself, I can't see the hub clear enough in the pic to make sure, but you would likely need:

- Cassette lock nut tool
- Chain whip
- Cone wrenches in the right size (these are flat/skinny open end wrenches)
- Adjustable/Crescent wrench
- Bearing grease

You may have cartridge bearings, in which case your overhaul job is simpler. But note that if the problem is the freehub and not the hub bearings then the freehub overhaul job is much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a new wheel. What has probably happened is your drum brake ('roller-brakes' as Shimano calls them) has seized on.

A good local bike repair shop can help you of course, but if you want to get into the roller brake yourself there are resources online to help with that.

A good place to start is this Sheldon Brown page: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rollerbrakes.html

If you google 'service shimano roller brake' for videos you'll get some hits.

The first thing I would do is remove the brake unit and a check the axle spins in the hub to confirm the brake is the problem. Then determine if the brake can be serviced or needs replacing. Removing the brake unit is quite simple I believe, just undoing a nut on the axle.

If it turns out the hub bearings are the problem it may be repairable. Without knowing what model hub it I can't give more detailed advice.